Как найти количество помеченных связных графов?

2

Задача похожа на codeforces 1009D, но только с одним числом в вводе
Можете пожалуйста написать способ нахождения помеченных связных графов когда на вход подается только одно число?(если не затрудняет то с кодом)

Степень n-1 должна быть у одной вершины. Отделим её и поищем решение задачи для количества графов, у которых ни одна из вершин не имеет максимальной степени.
А тема такая, оказывается, есть. Посчитаем это количество для n-1 вершин и умножим на n
 result = n * numconn(n-1)

Получим 3, 16, 205, 4608... Остаётся перевести на арифметику по модулю 1000000007 (-1 в степени при этом лучше будет по-простому сделать - то плюс, то минус)

Как можно оптимизировать программу? Было предложено такое решение, но мне как новичку трудно это воспринять до конца и написать код: https://qna.habr.com/q/1356916

Вычислений там не так уж много, но арифметику по модулю использовать же нужно.  но мне как новичку  - но это нетривиальная задача.
